# How to clone AND downscale 2560x1080 resolution for both display and streaming

Tags: streaming, hardware

The current setup is:

```
   ______________
  | Computer     |
  |______________|
 DVI |        | HDMI
     |        |
HDMI |        | HDMI
  ___|____   _|_________
 | Video  | | 2560x1080 |
 |Streamer| | monitor   |
 |________| |___________|
 eth |
```

So, basically I just have an ultrawide monitor running at 2560x1080 connected to a PC. I also want to stream a clone of what is displayed on that ultrawide monitor so I can see what's happening over LAN. I use an external streaming hardware box (Antrica brand) for that, and have no problems using resolutions lower than 2560x1080.

The problem is that my streaming hardware (and many other external video hardware) supports only resolutions up to 1920x1080.

So I need to downscale, resize and/or crop the cloned video output of the computer which goes to the streamer. This leads to my actual question: how to do that?

Ideally, there would be some kind of a hardware video downscaler box between the computer and streamer. The box should accept 2560x1080 input. Even more ideally I would have an option to choose whether to downscale or crop the inputted video. Do such boxes exist? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Does it have to be a hardware solution? ffmpeg could do this in software.

Comment: Preferably yes, because I want to avoid performance impacts of software solutions. However, I could try this out. Could you please help me getting started in doing this with ffmpeg?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit. Sorry for forgetting to mention that.